# QEMU doesn't boot iso file in UEFI

Tags: virtual-machine, uefi, iso

### The Problem

I would like to run a Windows 8.1 iso inside QEMU KVM. For this I have downloaded the necessary OVMF files (from [here](https://www.kraxel.org/repos/jenkins/edk2/)). I can successfully boot a Windows 10 in UEFI mode, but with the same settings, I can't seem to be capable of achieving the same with version 8.1. I have checked the iso file for clues, but according to `dumpet` it has no problem whatsoever:

```
%./dumpet -i Windows_8.1.iso 


Validation Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x01 (Validation Entry)
    PlatformId: 0x00 (80x86)
    ID: "Microsoft Corporation"
    Checksum: 0x494c
    Key bytes: 0x55aa
Boot Catalog Default Entry:
    Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load segment: 0x0 (0000:7c00)
    System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 8 (0x0008)
    Load LBA: 5184 (0x00001440)
Section Header Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x91 (Final Section Header Entry)
    PlatformId: 0xef (EFI)
    Section Entries: 1
    ID: ""
Boot Catalog Section Entry:
    Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load address: 0 (0x0000)
    System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 1 (0x0001)
    Load LBA: 2156 (0x0000086c)
```

I have also tried checking the difference between dumpet results of the two windows versions:

```
Validation Entry:                       Validation Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x01 (Validation Entry)           Header Indicator: 0x01 (Validation Entry)
    PlatformId: 0x00 (80x86)                    PlatformId: 0x00 (80x86)
    ID: "Microsoft Corporation"                 ID: "Microsoft Corporation"
    Checksum: 0x494c                        Checksum: 0x494c
    Key bytes: 0x55aa                       Key bytes: 0x55aa
Boot Catalog Default Entry:                 Boot Catalog Default Entry:
    Entry is bootable                       Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation             Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load segment: 0x0 (0000:7c00)             Media load segment: 0x0 (0000:7c00)
    System type: 0 (0x00)                       System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 8 (0x0008)                    Load Sectors: 8 (0x0008)
    Load LBA: 5184 (0x00001440)               |     Load LBA: 546 (0x00000222)
Section Header Entry:                       Section Header Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x91 (Final Section Header Entry)     Header Indicator: 0x91 (Final Section Header Entry)
    PlatformId: 0xef (EFI)                      PlatformId: 0xef (EFI)
    Section Entries: 1                      Section Entries: 1
    ID: ""                              ID: ""
Boot Catalog Section Entry:                 Boot Catalog Section Entry:
    Entry is bootable                       Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation             Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load address: 0 (0x0000)                  Media load address: 0 (0x0000)
    System type: 0 (0x00)                       System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 1 (0x0001)                    Load Sectors: 1 (0x0001)
    Load LBA: 2156 (0x0000086c)               |     Load LBA: 548 (0x00000224)
```

The .iso file contains the following files:

```
%tree -L 2 /mnt    

├── autorun.inf
├── boot
│   ├── bcd
│   ├── bootfix.bin
│   ├── boot.sdi
│   ├── bootsect.exe
│   ├── en-us
│   ├── etfsboot.com
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── memtest.exe
│   └── resources
├── bootmgr
├── bootmgr.efi
├── efi
│   ├── boot
│   └── microsoft
├── setup.exe
├── sources
│   ├── *MANY .dll FILES*
└── support
    └── logging
```

### Question

Should I try a different iso as this is corrupt, or the problem is related to the VM itself?

Comment: You could try installing Windows 8.1 in another virtual machine software like VirtualBox, then importing the hard disk into QEMU.